# Issues when solving the N+1 query problem with JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, microservices

**Pre-requisites**

I have the following database structure:

1. The list of tables includes A, B, C, D, and E
2. All of these tables have a BIGINT primary key
3. Table A represents the base entity
4. Table B, C, and D contain a foreign key to table A, essentially creating a 1:N relationship from A
5. Table E has a foreign key referencing table D, i.e, a 1:N relationship from table D
6. All of the foreign keys are indexed

**Problem Description**

The goal here is to be able to fetch the base entity with all its referenced entities using JPA given a few `where` filers.

Previously, I was relying on the OSIV filter. So, at the time of querying, the base entity without is referenced entities were being queried and, at the view layer when Jackson tries to access the getters to formulate the response, additional queries were being executed to fetch the referenced entities. As you can see this caused what is termed the N+1 query problem. Additionally as part of the base query, offset and limit were set for pagination.

To fix the N+1 query problem while ensuring that the pagination happens at the DB level and not in-memory at the application level, I did the following:

1. The first query executed was to retrieve the distinct ids from the table A which matched the filters, ordered as per parameters, and were paginated.

```
select distinct id from A 
left join B on B.a_id = A.id
left join C on C.a_id = A.id
left join D on D.a_id = A.id
left join E on E.d_id = D.id
where A.attribute_1 = ? and B.attribute_2 = ? ...
```

2. The second query executed was to retrieve the complete JPA Entity A which includes all the referenced entities where ids were one of the ids retrieved from query 1

```
select * from A 
left outer join B on B.a_id = A.id
left outer join C on C.a_id = A.id
left outer join D on D.a_id = A.id
left outer join E on E.d_id = D.id
where A.id in (:ids)
```

**Issue**

The issue I'm facing is that post this optimization, surprisingly the performance has degraded significantly. It is to be noted that it is the query #2 which is causing the degrade in performance. One observation made is that as the entries in C increase the query #2 is slowing further. Has anyone faced a similar issue in the past or if I'm doing something wrong please help let me know the resolution.

Comment: I am far from being a DB optimization expert; with that in mind, I think that, in principle, what you are doing is reasonable. I wonder, why are you OUTER JOINing in the 2nd query, while INNER in the first? Can you make Hibernate log the actual SQL query and run EXPLAIN to get some insight?

Comment: I did run an explain on the actual query, only to find that the query is using the indexes as expected. And for why the outer join, afaik they both essentially mean the same @NikosParaskevopoulos

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos - MySQL ignores `OUTER` and `INNER`.

Comment: @ABAA - Using `LEFT` means that you are expecting the "right" row to be missing some of the time.  If this is not the case, remove the word `LEFT`.

Comment: @RickJames `LEFT` is intentional